# How to Extract Particular Data From JSON Python

Tags: python, json

I have this json:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/12w7Kx1.png]

how to parse all the names, inside book, i can get one by:

```
import requests
url = "https://www.storytel.com/api/search.action?q=white%20feather"
r = requests.get(url)
cont = r.json()
# print(cont)
print(cont['books'][0]['book']['name'])
```

but how can i get all the "name"?
i have tried this but did not work:

```
data = cont['books']

for book in data:
    print(cont['book']['name'])
```

error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "testing.py", line 12, in module> print(cont['book']['name']) KeyError: 'book'
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail as to how this "did not work"?

Comment: Can you also post the traceback!?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(cont['book']['name'])
KeyError: 'book'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using the *variable* (as opposed to the *string*) `book` in your loop.

Comment: I am sorry what does it mean?

Comment: You wrote `for book`..., but never actually used `book`.

Comment: you are right. thank you as a first answer i will give you the the answer.

Comment: tbh it’s also the only answer that explains the cause of the issue. I think that deserves an upvote by itself.

Answer (score -2):

You are referring to the incorrect variable inside the loop, instead of cont you should refer book instance.

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://www.storytel.com/api/search.action?q=white%20feather"
r = requests.get(url)
cont = r.json()
data = cont['books']
for book in data:
    print(book['book']['name']) # here instead of pointing to Book instance, you are pointing to cont dictionary which is creating the issue
```

Output :

```
The White Feather
The White Feather
Little White Feather
The White Feather Murders
The White Feather Killer
The White Feather Hex
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).